# problem with highcharts series option

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, highcharts

Hi i am having problem with my highcharts 'series' options. i initialized the chart options as below:

```
            var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Weight Monitor',
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Date Measurement'
                },
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Weight (in Lbs)'
                }
            },
            series: []
    };
```

I kept the categories: [] blank so that i can put the values in categories later. Same thing i did with my series options. I kept the data:[] as blank to fill it later. Now i wrote the code to fill the data.

```
                var lines = [
                [2011,150],
                [2012,121],
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.toString().split(",");
            $.each (items, function(itemNo, item) {

                if(itemNo == 0){
                    alert("itemNo: " + itemNo + " item: " + item);
                    options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    alert(options.xAxis.categories);
                }

                else {
                            var series = {
                                    data: []
                            };
                    alert("itemNo: " + itemNo + " item: " + item);
                    options.series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    alert(options.series.data);
                };
            });
        });
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Now when i execute this code, my categories[] is getting values properly, but the execution gets stuck when it is at "options.series.data.push(parseFloat(item))". I am getting the proper value in the "alert("itemNo: " + itemNo + " item: " + item);". but just after that it hangs while pushing the item in series.data[]

any idea what is the problem. and i am running this javascript in php project so don't know if there is any issue because of the language. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `options.series.data.push(parseFloat(item))`.

If you look at your options object, you can see that your series array is empty. You can ad series object in your options definition as follows -

```
series: [{
    data: []
}]
```

Also the line

```
var series = {
    data: []
};
```

is of no use.